# Accessing phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, phpmyadmin

On a new webserver (Centos 6.8) I  installed phpMyAdmin via the CentOS package in order to make updates easier. It installed in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin.
I gave ownership of all the files in there to the user and group that Apache runs as, and set permissions of 744.

I have set up a VirtualHost sql.example.com - for security I have not created a DNS record - the one or two people who will use it can use their hosts file.

However, I cannot access it, with the error message saying access denied due to server configuration.
Which of the following do I need to do...

1. change ownership of the directory itself (usr/share/phpMyAdmin)?
2. point the virtualHost to /var/www/sql.example.com/public_html and
   create a simlink? or
3. create /var/www/sql.example.com and move all
   the files there? (and will this break updates via Yum?

Comment: Well, first, you broke the permissions. There was no need to alter them in any way.

Comment: really? The permissions were rw_ ___ ___

Comment: How did you configure your httpd server to access phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Restore the File Permissions and you need to make below changes in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` file.

Make sure you have allowed PhpMyadmin directory accessible. Comment `Deny from` section and add `allow from 0.0.0.0` if you want phpMyadmin to be accessible from any IP.

for eg (Apache 2.2 version):

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   allow from 192.168.2.0/24  #if you wish to allow only specific IPs
</Directory>
```